# How to include only a single file in sonar build.xml

Tags: java, sonarqube

How do I include only a single file in sonar build.xml?

I know how to exclude selected files for Sonar, but I want to now how to include selected files.

Answer (score 4):

See [http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus](https://web.archive.org/web/20140326192943/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus), "sonar.inclusions" property.